# I want to change a category name/text link to a picture in the main navigation bar

Tags: category, ce-1.9.1.0, rwd-theme

My magento store is version 1.9.1
I'm using a modified version of the rwd default theme.
By default, in the main top navigation bar your category names appear as text which links to their corresponding pages. I want to change one of my category names from this text to a small image/ .png because I want one of my categories to be a brand and I'd like to show off that logo there. I don't want to change all the category names, just that specific one. What can I do?

Comment: i can't understand can you please explain with screen shot

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4dcfeeadbe037390817b70411a4348ca 

This is the Category name. Instead of saying the category name I want it to be a small image of my choosing. For instance, I could change it to a star to look like this:

https://gyazo.com/b6f28909652128e3730f884bcaf97ed1

Comment: You want a background image for that vip

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by background. I do want to replace the image completely. No more "VIP", just my image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS:

```
a[href$="/vip.html"] {
    background: url("path/to/image.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

A big negative `text-indent` is one of the many methods to hide text from an element, then you set it to a fixed width and assign a background image